# Algorithm for mongo objectid filed in mongodb and how to get last 24 hour data from mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Is there any way to get objectids that are genrated in last 24 hours in mongo collection based on time stamp on objectid and what is the algorithm to genrate objectid in mongodb .

Comment: Are you using a specific language?

Comment: i am using bash to execute this queries.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get objectids that are genrated in last 24 hours in mongo collection based on time stamp on objectid

You can call JavaScript code such as:

```
date = new Date()
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)
yesterday = Math.floor(date.getTime()/1000).toString(16)
db.coll.find({_id : {$gt : new ObjectId(yesterday + "0000000000000000")}} , {_id:1})
```

The first and second statements are straightforward: yesterday's date.

Third row creates a 4-Byte Hex String of yesterday. Which are the 4 leftmost bytes of ObjectId.

Then, you pad the 8 rightmost bytes of the ObjectId with zero's as you don't care about those. These are mac address(3), pid(2) and a running counter(3)

All you have to now is query your collection (`coll` in the example) and return the _id's

> what is the algorithm to genrate objectid in mongodb

[There you are](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have one more question. i have list of mongo database names in the host.I want to execute below .js script by passing dataname as argument.

Comment: You can use `db.adminCommand('listDatabases')` from your script to read a list of databases or use any js mechanism to read from file